# Mercury WYSIWYG Editor won't work on assets' subfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wysiwyg, asset-pipeline, mercury-editor

[Mercury Editor](http://jejacks0n.github.com/mercury/)

I already excluded `mercury.js` from `application.js` changing `require_tree .` to `require_directory .` and moving `mercury.js` to a subfolder called `mercury` inside `assets/javascripts`.

So everything else on my app is working great and is not loading anything of mercury.

Now on `layouts/mercury.html.erb`

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'mercury/mercury' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.7', 'mercury/mercury' %>
```

And

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
          // Set to the url that you want to save any given page to, leave null for default handling.
          var saveUrl = null;

          // Instantiate the PageEditor
          new Mercury.PageEditor(saveUrl, {
            saveStyle:  'form', // 'form', or 'json' (default json)
            saveMethod: null, // 'PUT', or 'POST', (create, vs. update -- default PUT)
            visible:    true  // boolean - if the interface should start visible or not
          });
</script>
```

But when the editor loads I get this error:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Mercury.PageEditor')`

Is is something with the subfolder?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that this is due to the mercury library hogging the 'mercury' path.

If you rake routes you'll see this

```
Routes for Mercury::Engine:
mercury_editor  /editor(/*requested_uri)(.:format)        mercury#edit
                /mercury/:type/:resource(.:format)        mercury#resource
                /mercury/snippets/:name/options(.:format) mercury#snippet_options
                /mercury/snippets/:name/preview(.:format) mercury#snippet_preview
```

It's kind of confusing because the file you get when you request yourhost://assets/mercury/mercury.js is the mercury library file. if you name the folder 'mercury_assets' or really anything other than 'mercury' it will work.

i wouldn't mess around with trying to change the routes unless you were sure mercury could find the necessary libraries.